# How do I save part of a string that includes a number, in Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, selenium, ide

I'm trying to save 135224 in the example below to utilize on another site.

```
store text | xpath=//b[contains(., 'Authorization Request - Confirmation Number : 135224')] | string
```

Currently, I'm getting an error of :

> Failed: missing ) after argument list

Here is my command of what I've tried in Selenium :

```
run script | javascript(myString(); function myString() {var auth = 'Authorization Request - Confirmation Number: ()' var confNum = auth.slice(47,52))} | auth Num
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you put last "`)`" to wrong place, please try following :

```
 run script | javascript(myString(); function myString() {var auth = 'Authorization Request - Confirmation Number: ()' var confNum = auth.slice(47,52)}) | auth Num
```